# Multiple Participants data entry on event not working

Tags: civievent

I have an event setup to allow registration of multiple participants but the participant number drop down does not show
[image: Missing number of participants drop down]

The following html is within the page so ought to show

```
<select onchange="allowParticipant()" name="additional_participants" id="additional_participants" class="crm-form-select">
    <option value="">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
</select>
```

I have tried on multiple themes

Php 7.3.27
Civicrm 5.36.0
Drupal 7.78

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I discovered a {display:none} css style in a custom.css that was being applied to this field

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if the field is hidden by doing inspect element on browser? It may be possible that the field is hidden by your custom css (`display : none`). If so you need to over-write the css to `display : block` or remove the line from css file

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean - the field is enabled on the 'Online Registration' page which is how I get the title and description of it showing

Comment: I meant if the field is hidden on front end page via css... which i believe was

Comment: Pradeep can you rewrite above as an Answer so someone doesn't convert to Comment?